# Restricting Work Items for External Users

Tags: azure-devops

I'd like to restrict external users to only be able to update a custom field (Approvals with a control extension) and the discussion field within a work item.  I can't quite figure out how to find that granularity. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the following:

1. Create a group that will be authorized to write the fields in question
2. Edit the process for your project (Organization Settings -> Process -> Your process)
3. Select the work item type (Bug, Issue, User Story, etc) you wish to modify
4. Select the Rules tab, and create a new rule
5. For Condition, specify "Current user is not member of group", and then select that group
6. For Action, create an action for each field you wish to control, setting "Then" to "Make read-only", and select the field you wish to restrict.
7. Turn off read-write access to all fields you want to restrict from users not in your group.

Comment: I think this is going to work - thank you!!

Comment: Quick question on this - I see "Make read-only" but I don't see an option for "Make read-write" or something similar.  What would be best for this set of users would be to make them Readers of the project and then make the two specific fields they need editable.  Managing by exception :)

Comment: removed that note. I was wrong about explicitly making it read-write.

Comment: Ok thanks - not sure this is going to be sustainable for my solution for an external user, as there are so many fields and boards that the user will still be able to read/edit, and the issue of having to configure these permissions per process.  

Will continue to research - maybe something in the review portion of the Modern Requirements extension?  

If all else fails, we'll continue updating info with them.

I appreciate your time!